# trying to access nested json value for v-select (itemProps) in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to make a v-select component in vuetify which get data from a API and show it as options , but the bizzare thing is the recieved json data have an object inside the object and it can not be accessed :( 
 here is my code :

```js
<template>
  <Comp v-model="trainer" class="mt-10 mb-20 text" />
</template>

<script>
  import Comp from './Comp.vue'
  export default {
    components: {
      Comp,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        trainer: '',
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

and here is the Comp component :

```js
<template>
  <v-select
    label=" trainer"
    v-model="selected"
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :item-props="itemProps"
    :items="items"
  ></v-select>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['value'],
    data() {
      return {
        selected: this.value,
        items: [
          {
            id: 7,
            user: {
              first_name: 'john',
              last_name: 'Doe',
              phone_number: '0910087634',
              email: 'test@gmail.com',
            },
            specializations: null,
            bio: '  hello',
            image: '',
            birthdate: '2024-01-01',
            gender: 'male',
            experience_years: 7,
          },
        ],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      itemProps(item) {
        return {
          title: item.user.first_name,
          subtitle: item.id,
        }
      },
    },
    computed: {
      selected: {
        get() {
          return this.value
        },
        set(val) {
          this.$emit('input', val)
        },
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

this part of code is working fine :

```js
itemProps(item) {
        return {
          title: item.bio,
          subtitle: item.id,
        }
      },
```

but when you want to pass `item.user.first_name` instead of `item.bio`, it gets errors and I have no idea.
here is the [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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):

Comment: The `itemProps` function is called twice, once for the item and then again for the selected value, which is an empty string. When item is an empty string, `item.bio` is undefinded, as is `item.user`, so accessing `item.user.first_name` throws an error (no property first_name on undefined). Passing in `null` instead of an empty string fixes the issue, though you probably want to either make the component check the prop type or make the function work with strings too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, I identified two problems:

- you have an ambigous properties (selected as a data and selected as a computed), remove the **seleted** data to solve this ambiguity,
- you don't check the selected value if it has **user** as a nested object or not. If the selected value have not a nested **user** object, **item.user.first_name** does not work (this is your case as a initial value, selected is an empty string).

Here is a solution for your problem:

```
<template>
  <v-select
    label=" trainer"
    v-model="selected"
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :item-props="itemProps"
    :items="items"
  ></v-select>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['value'],
    data() {
      return {
        items: [
          {
            id: 7,
            user: {
              first_name: 'john',
              last_name: 'Doe',
              phone_number: '0910087634',
              email: 'test@gmail.com',
            },
            specializations: null,
            bio: '  hello',
            image: '',
            birthdate: '2024-01-01',
            gender: 'male',
            experience_years: 7,
          },
        ],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      itemProps(item) {
        return {
          title: item.user?.first_name,
          subtitle: item.id,
        }
      },
    },
    computed: {
      selected: {
        get() {
          return this.value
        },
        set(val) {
          this.$emit('input', val)
        },
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks I actually added it because for example when you pass : `title: item.user?.first_name + ' ' + item.user?.last_name,` at first, in v-select, it becomes:`undefined undefined`.

Comment: @Elias in this case you should coalesce the firstname and lastname.

Comment: great I added this and it works :
` const fullName = \`${item.user?.first_name ?? ''} ${
          item.user?.last_name ?? ''
        }\` `